# Как получить username пользователя, который присоединился к чату. Aiogram

Tags: python, telegram-bot, бот, aiogram

Мне нужно получить username пользователя, который только что присоединился к чату. (aiogram)

```
@dp.message_handler(content_types=['new_chat_members'])
async def new_user_joined(message: types.Message):
    username = ?

    await message.answer(username)
```

Аналог Telebot:

```
@bot.message_handler(content_types=["new_chat_members"])
def handler_new_member(message):
    username = message.new_chat_member.first_name
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, username)
```

Понимаю, что вопрос довольно нелепый, но перегуглил всё и не нашел.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Отличий никаких не будет, потому что используется один и тот же API:

```py
@dp.message_handler(content_types=['new_chat_members'])
async def new_user_joined(message: types.Message):
    for new_member in message.new_chat_members
        first_name = member.first_name # Не может быть пустым
        last_name = member.last_name # Может быть пустым
        username = member.username # Может быть пустым

        # Тут делайте всё, что хотите делать с новым пользователем(-ми)
```

Comment: Да, действительно... Просто я через for и не пробовал)
Спасибо огромное!